# Editing using AXF file

Tags: arcmap, arcpad

I have problem editing data in ArcPad because of the limitation of software. Can you help me? My client wants to do editing in ArcPad but because of the limitation, I am trying to find a solution to help them by using AXF file out of ArcPad. Do you know how to edit axf file in ArcMap ? But I am not working in shapefile but checkout data from feature layer which is carrying subtype and domain. Looking some help from you.

Comment: Since version 10.1, you can _see_ an AXF in ArcMap, but not edit it. See [View an AXF in ArcGIS Desktop](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcpad/10.2/app/index.html#/View_an_AXF_in_ArcGIS_Desktop/00s10000013n000000/)

Comment: do you have any idea how to edit the data?

Comment: What are the limitations in ArcPad that are the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you initially checked out your data from a geodatabase you should be able to check it back in to edit it. What are the "limitations" of your software? If you also checked the axf file out to edit in Arcpad, then you will be able to edit it in Arcpad.

Comment: we checkout the axf file through workflow in HQ office and send the file to fieldwork officer, they download the file through workflow manager and collect new feature, but before sync the updated data, they want to do manual editng such as duplicate feature, split, merge, copy and paste and those editing that arcpad dont have the capabilities, so if they sync the data without editing, the data will be send into the checkout version. To maintain the quality and integrity of the data, they want do data editing soon after fieldwork, otherwise they need to wait HQ to checkout from sde to gdb .